# Serve RMarkdown outputs without version controlling them

Tags: r, git, r-markdown, github-pages, bookdown

We frequently use RMarkdown based packages to create websites with R (`bookdown`, `blogdown`, `distill`...) and use github-pages to serve the html files  via the url `username.github.io/repo`.

In this approach, the ouput (i.e. html / css) files are also version controlled, and are frequently included in commits by mistake (`git commit -a`). This is annoying since these files clutter the commit and often lead to fictitious files conflicts.

Ideally, the outputfiles would not be version controlled at all, since the binary files (images) additionally bloat the repo. So I'm looking for a solution where:

- Git ignores the output files *completely* but provides an alternative (but comparable<sup>1</sup>) method to gh-pages to serve them
- Git ignores the output files *temporally* and committing / pushing them to gh-pages is done in a separate, explicit command

<sup>1</sup>: The method should be command line based and provide a nice URL to access the website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a python installation on your computer, you can use **[GitHub Pages Import](https://pypi.org/project/ghp-import/)**, a tool designed specifically for this purpose.

You need a python installation since it has to be installed with pip, but once it's installed it integrates beautifully with into an R / RMarkdown workflow.

Once it's installed (`pip install ghp-import`), you can run `ghp-import docs` (assuming `docs` is where your RMarkdown outputs are stored).

There are a bunch of practical options that you can use, including `-p` to additionally push the changes to your remote after the commit.

Answer (score 1):

You could have `.html`, `.css` etc. ignored in the `main` and all other branches but the branch, for example, the `gh-page` branch, where your github-page is built from.

Git does not support different `.ignore` files in different branches so you would have to set up a bash script that replaces the ignore file each time you checkout a new branch. See here for how to do that: https://gist.github.com/wizioo/c89847c7894ede628071

Maybe not the elegant solution you were hoping for but it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seemed like a plausible way to go, but looking through the gist it seemed like a very hacky solution with more overhead that I was looking for. I ended up accepting my own answer, a solution that I found out about by chance!

Comment: Your solution looks neat indeed. I might try it out for my own projects!

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Git to ignore the folder the book gets built into.

So, for example, by default bookdown puts all the built files in a folder called "_book"

Just add the following line to the .gitignore file in your project.

`_book`

Then you can work on your book and build it and push changes without worrying about the site being updated.

To update the site, you want to create a gh-pages branch that is only used for the hosted content. Do that with these commands from in your book folder:

```
git checkout --orphan gh-pages
git rm -rf .

# create a hidden file .nojekyll
touch .nojekyll
git add .nojekyll

git commit -m"Initial commit"
git push origin gh-pages
```

Make sure (once you put your book content in that branch) that GitHub is set to use that branch for hosting, rather than the folder you were using before.

Then, you can switch back to your main branch with the following command:

```
git checkout master
```

Next, you will clone your gh-pages branch into your main project:

```
git clone -b gh-pages https://github.com/yourprojecturl.git book-output
```

Then, when you have a version of the built book (in the _book folder) ready to use as your live site, use the following commands to copy the content into the book-output folder and push that to the gh-pages branch where the live site is:

```
cd book-output
git rm -rf *
cp -r ../_book/* ./
git add --all *
git commit -m"Update the book"
git push -q origin gh-pages
```

You can continue to use this last set of commands whenever you have a version in _book that you're ready to push live.

Comment: But how would I serve the files as a Website?

Comment: There are two ways of using GitHub pages to host content. One, is to specify a folder in your main branch that gets hosted. The other is to use a separate branch as the hosted site. That's the method I recommend. So you ignore the build folder and then, whenever you want, you push the contents of the _book folder into the gh-pages branch. Instructions can be found here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/github.html

Comment: I should also add, that technically it is *impossible* to use GitHub pages for hosting your content without version control of some sort. But my method keeps your main branch code separate from your website code, which is what you want so it won't get in the way, conflict, etc.

Comment: > *So you ignore the build folder and then, whenever you want, you push the contents of the _book folder into the gh-pages branch* I find this a very interesting approach that I was never sure was possible. So how can I commit / push an ignored folder to a seperate brach? The link you mentioned does not go into this

Comment: It does a little bit further down. I'm editing my answer to give the full info.